# Syncfusion's EJ2 Dropdown Clear Button

Tags: angular, angular5, syncfusion

I'm trying to use Syncfusion's EJ2 components in an angular app but i'm stacked on DropDownList component as some features are poorly documented till now.
In component's API documentation there is the showclearbutton property but it doesn't seem to work. My code:

```
<ej-dropdownlist #customerAutoComplete id="ddCustomerId" [dataSource]="customers" [fields]="customerFields" [query]="customerQuery" sortOrder="Ascending" [allowFiltering]="true" [showClearButton]="true"></ej-dropdownlist>
```

I can't find another way to clear selected value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have confirmed that the issue with (“Dropdownlist Clear Button not visible”) is a defect and we have logged a defect report. The fix will be rollout on upcoming patch release 24th Jan 2018.

Please let us know if you have any concern, we will happy to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for patience.

We are fixed you reported issue (Dropdownlist Clear Button not visible) and rolled out in  v15.4.26-preview release. Now, you can upgrade the ej2-dropdowns npm package on your application.

NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns

Please let us know, if you have any other concern, we will happy to assist you.